# Не запускается rails проект после bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

После выполнения команды bundle update больше не запускается проект. 
Пишет вот такую ошибку:

```
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring nio4r-2.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.1.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.0
Ignoring oj-3.1.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine oj --version 3.1.4
Ignoring pg-0.21.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.21.0
Ignoring puma-3.9.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.9.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.0
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
```

Выполнения данного рода команд `gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0` не к чему не приводит.
Так же удалял все `gem` и установил заново. Тоже ничего. Те же ошибки, но уже с другими гемами..  Среда разработки `c9.io`

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.3.3'
end

group :development, :production do
  # facebook OmniAuth
  gem 'omniauth-facebook'
  #Create JSON structures via a Builder-style DSL
  gem 'jbuilder'
  gem 'rails'
  gem 'oj' 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'paperclip'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'bootstrap'
  gem 'simple_token_authentication', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'kaminari'
end
group :production do
  gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  # gem 'faker'
  # gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  # gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: какие-нибудь менеджеры версий руби используются?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman возможно я не правильно вас понял, но ruby 2.4.0 устанавливал через команду rbenv install 2.4.0

Comment: правильно поняли. какие версии у вас установлены? посмотрите в `~/.rbenv/versions`

Comment: @MikhailVaysman `rbenv versions
  system
* 2.4.0 (set by /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/version)`

Comment: это единственная версия, которая установлена?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman еще установлен `rvm 1.27.0 (latest)` rbenv -v:   2.4.0 и систем. больше ничего не пишет

Comment: @MikhailVaysman оказывается что в система использувала rvm и там были установлены 4 версии руби, и rvm  использовал 2.3, а не 2.4. я все удалил и поставил только 2.4. И сделал bundle install. все заработало. Спасибо за правильное направление. Вы спасли мой курсач)

Comment: я тогда восстановлю ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорей всего у вас **gems** были установлены под другую версию **ruby**. Вы берите правильную версию и выполните

```
gem pristine --all
```

Это должно помочь.

Так же можно попробовать запустить повторную установку

```
bundle install
```

Comment: версия руби не изменялась при этом. изначально проект строился на 2.4.0 так и осталось. после `gem pristine --all` те же ошибки

Comment: ответ не помог?

Comment: нет, пишет те же ошибки

Comment: только команда `gem pristine --all` не нужна была, а просто удалить все лишние руби версии `rvm uninstall version`.

Comment: нужна была бы, если бы вы версию переключили. у вас **bundle** запускался под другой версией.

Comment: буду знать на будущие )

Comment: я вас специально спросил про версии. но вы сказали только об одной.

Comment: я не думал что у меня еще й стоит руби через `rvm` стоит, потому что я ставил только `rbenv`. а на `с9.io` он дефолтно стоит через `rvm` все остальные версии(